# How to test LINQ to SQL Conflict Management

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, conflict

I have implemented the following solution for conflict management in my web application:

```
Using transaction As New TransactionScope()
    Do
        Try 
            ' Make changes to the data'
            db.SubmitChanges()
            transaction.Complete()
            ' Exit the loop when no conflicts occurred'
            Exit Do 
        Catch conflictEx As ChangeConflictException
            For Each prob As ObjectChangeConflict
                In manager.db.ChangeConflicts

                prob.Resolve(
                    RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues)
            Next
        End Try
    Loop
End Using
```

Essentially, if someone else quickly changes the data while it's still being processed, the program should re-read all the data and recalculate the changes from scratch.

But I'm unable to find any way to test this conflict management solution. I've tried setting a breakpoint before transaction.Complete() and modifying the table data in Visual Studio, but it keeps showing a timeout error while the breakpoint is set.

Any other reliable way of testing it?

ADD: Also tried inserting a Thread.Sleep(10000) call and changing the data in VS - VS query seems to freeze until the thread sleep call is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instantiating a new datacontext right before (submitChanges) and updating data for that context saving it, then allowing the first datacontext to submit its changes?